# Angular ng-change firing before ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

console.log("lame", $scope.selectedId);  still says 2 when the ng-change fires ... but the {{selectedId}} in my view updates to the correct id selected from the drop down. It's as if the ng-change is firing before the ng-model is updating.

My controller

```
$scope.selectedId = 2

$scope.getResource = function(){
    console.log("lame", $scope.selectedId);
    Service.getResource($scope.id).then(function(response){
        $scope.resource = response;
    });
};
```

Markup

```
{{selectedId}}
<select ng-model="selectedId" ng-change="getResource()" type="text" class="form-control"
        ng-options="id as id for id in idList">
</select>
```

I'm using angular 1.2. Any insight?

Comment: cannot replicate your issue, I created a plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/nsCKVMH8Mec7LQSf2n5x?p=preview) with your code, but console.log is correct. Please try to reproduce mentioned by you issue on my plunker

Comment: I couldn't reproduce either. (angular 1.2) http://plnkr.co/edit/yf0oKshHkqWlCoOFINSQ?p=preview

Comment: This is so weird... Everything is the same in your plnkr...

Comment: I don't know what happened. It just started working. Mind you I always clear my browser cache when refreshing.